# Does Apache Superset support Web Components? Instead of using embedded iframe

Tags: apache-superset

I'm using Angular 11. Is there anyway to integrate Apache Superset web components into Angular11 ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Superset is built out of React components, some of which (e.g. viz plugins) can be used in other React applications. It's *kind of possible* to build React components into Angular applications using wrappers and various lifecycle bindings, but it's not super straightforward. That said, I'm not sure what  components you're looking to take advantage of, but I'd be happy to elaborate if I'm able.